# Does {{ ref () }} has any limitations or am I doing something wrong? (dbt + snowflake)

Tags: dbt

I have a view model with multiple union all of different sources data.
Let's call it `"v_combined_data"`

Then there is a table model named `"fact_sales_transactions"` that uses this view.
In this model, I do a simple select from `{{ref ('v_combined_data') }}`  which should already indicate there's an order to execute this

However, there is a job running every day, and sometimes the table does not get all the data from the view model. The view has the correct data, but the table is incomplete. When I run the job manually again, without changing anything at all, the data gets completed.

**Here's what I already did**

- We use the `ref` function correctly.
- I analysed the DAG graph and it seems correct.
- I added the following comment to the beginning of the .sql model (https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/forcing-dependencies-depends-on-example-code/3558)
  `-- depends on: {{ ref('v_combined_data') }}`
- The job commands' list executes first the view and then the next command is to execute the table.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

NOTE: I noticed that this dbt project does not have a schema.yml set up, could this be a reason for this to happen?

Comment: schema.yml is meant for documentation, defining tests etc. I can't think of something obvious. Can you please edit your question to include the code of both the view and the model?

Comment: Could it be that the job sometimes fails to finish up, like timeout due to big amount of data, etc? I ran into a similar problem once because of this reason.

Comment: I don't know. v_combined_data is a complex view, but the fact_sales_transactions is a simple select from that table. 

My guess from what I've read is that the ref function has limitations when your table/view is complex, so the table fact_sales_transactions might start running before v_combined_data finishes its run.

Comment: What I did was split the job. And trigger the job that runs the fact_sales_transactions sometime after. ANd things have been going on.
Another solution that I thought about was splitting the v_combined_data into different tables and then making a union all (NOTE that v_combined_data is complex and huge because it joins different tables from different sources into one, and makes a union all of each of these sources.) So maybe spliting the joins for each source independently  - like intermediate tables - and then make a union of all those different tables would solve this